# Keras CNN-LSTM RuntimeError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use the following model Inceptionv3 base CNN and LSTM layer for a regression problem. My input data is pictures with continuous target values. I'd like to feed the sequence of images to a CNN and after to an LSTM layer. However i get a

```
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it
```

message. Any idea what can be the cause? I tried to find out in github and on several pages but i didnt succeed.

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, LSTM, TimeDistributed, Input
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, ReduceLROnPlateau
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# custom R2-score metrics for keras backend
#https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing/discussion/34019
from keras import backend as K

def r2_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true)))
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )  

train_data_dir = '...'
test_data_dir = '...'

train_df = pd.read_csv('...')
valid_df = pd.read_csv('...')

filepath_loss = '...'
filepath_csv = '...'

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,)


img_width, img_height = 380, 380
frames = 5
channels = 3

pictures = Input(shape=(frames, img_width, img_height, channels))

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_df,
directory=train_data_dir,
x_col="block_heights",
y_col="weighted_prices",
has_ext=False,      #x_col column doesnt has the file extensions
#subset="training",     if validation split is set in ImageDataGenerator
batch_size=16,
seed=42,
shuffle=False,
class_mode="other",  #for regression other should be used
target_size=(img_width, img_height))

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=valid_df,
directory=train_data_dir,
x_col="block_heights",
y_col="weighted_prices",
has_ext=False,              #x_col column doesnt has the file extensions
#subset="validation",      if validation split is set in ImageDataGenerator
batch_size=16,
seed=42,
shuffle=False,
class_mode="other",
target_size=(img_width, img_height))  

conv_base = InceptionV3(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3))
conv_base.trainable = True

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(conv_base))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

#error at callbacks if the learning rate is explicitly set somewhere
rms = RMSprop(lr=0.1, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=rms, metrics=['mae', r2_keras])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto'),
            ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.02, patience=3, min_lr=0.001),
            ModelCheckpoint(filepath_loss, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min'),
            CSVLogger(filepath_csv, separator = ",", append = False)]


history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, validation_data=valid_generator, validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, epochs=50, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Why are you using `TimeDistributed` layer? The generator would give batches of  images, so it does not make sense to use that layer.

Comment: I'd like to run an experiment if i could predict the target better, if the model takes sequences of images as inputs and their corresponding target values. I'd like to predict for example from 10 images and 10 target values the 11th target value for the 11th image

Comment: But the `ImageDatagenerator` would give you **batches of images** and not **batches of sequences of images**.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution, including the errors and their descriptions in my code?

Comment: One way is to wrap your current generator inside another generator and create batches of image sequences there. Another way is to write a custom generator from scratch that read the dataframe, load the images and generate the batches of image sequences optionally with a given sequence length and overlap between the batches. However, all this makes sense only if there is sequential order among the images; that's what the LSTM layer does (i.e. sequence processing). Otherwise I think it would be of no use.

Comment: Yes, the images have sequential order in time. Do you think that the code gave the runtime error because of the wrong use case of the TimeDistributed layers?

Comment: Can you please provide a code solution too for your generator, please? I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: @hk_03 Did you solve it, I am implementing similar thing and get dimension error